# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: javascript, google-maps, asynchronous

I'm using xammp the first-time up the server run nice and then shutdown the server and again up the server and execute the script is where I had errors.

Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

I'm trying to run first the xmlhttp and then draw the google map.

```
var myObj={};


var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {

    myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    console.log(myObj);

    }

};
xmlhttp.open("POST", "tPHP.php", true);
xmlhttp.send();



function initMap() {} 
$(() => {
  initMap = function() {

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 17,
      center: {lat: 8.650263, lng: -82.944570}
    });

    pintaMapa(map);
  }
})




function pintaMapa(map) {
  var datos= myObj["Posiciones"];
 // console.log(datos);
  var image = {
    url: 'iconoHospital.png',
    scaledSize : new google.maps.Size(50, 50),

  };

  for (var i = 0; i < datos.length; i++) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: {lat: parseFloat( datos[i].latitud), lng:parseFloat(datos[i].longitud)},
     map: map,
     title: datos[i].nombre,
     id: datos[i].id,
     direccion:"Barrio el invu "+ datos[i].nombre,
     icon: image
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you `console.log(datos)` and see what you are getting?

Comment: Include the error line number and other relevant information.

Comment: console.log(datos) is not empty

Comment: but i clean my browser and run the script againt, dont show me errors

Comment: if you log `datos` in `pintaMapa`, what do you get?  There is a race condition between loading the `map` (running the `initMap` function, which is most likely the callback function for the Google Maps Javascript API v3, but you didn't include that in your question) and the results being returned in the asynchronous XMLHttpRequest callback function running.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
   function initMap() {

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 17,
      center: {lat: 8.650263, lng: -82.944570}
    });


    datoss("tPHP.php",function (data){
     var myObj = JSON.parse(data.responseText);


  var datos= myObj["Posiciones"];

 console.log(datos);
  var image = {
    url: 'iconoHospital.png',
    scaledSize : new google.maps.Size(50, 50),

  };

  for (var i = 0; i < datos.length; i++) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: {lat: parseFloat( datos[i].latitud), lng:parseFloat(datos[i].longitud)},
     map: map,
     title: datos[i].nombre,
     id: datos[i].id,
     direccion:"Barrio el invu "+ datos[i].nombre,
     icon: image
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
      alert(this.direccion);
    });

  }

  });

  }


  function datoss(url,callback) {

    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
        callback(xmlhttp, xmlhttp.status);
      }
    };

    xmlhttp.open('GET', url, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
  }


  function doNothing() {}
```